# Looper.loop doesn't allow execute another work in Android thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created thread that connects my app throught socket. But I need to read and write data from/to socket in this thread. I can't do this because Looper.loop doesn't allow this. How can I read messages that come to this thread from main UI and check if new data is coming to socket?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText textOut;
    TextView textIn;
    //Socket soc;
    int port=1000;
    EditText text ;
    public Handler h;
    public Handler mHandler;
    String str;
    Message msg1;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    h = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            str=bundle.getString("TCP");
            text.setText(str);
        };
      };

    thread.start(); 
     //thread.start(); 

 }

    public void send(View view){
        Log.d("TCP", "C: READ123");

        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    Message msg;
    BufferedWriter out;

    @Override
    public void run() {

    Looper.prepare();
    mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // обрабатываем входящие сообщения
            Log.d("MY", "RECEIVE");

        }
    }; 

    //LOOP
    //Looper.loop();

     char[] mData = new char[4096];
     String s="";
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        try {
            try {

             InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.75");
             Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting...");
             Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 1000);
             String message = "komand1";

              try {

                 out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())); 
                    // out.println(message);
                     Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                     Log.d("TCP", "C: Sent.");

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                 } finally {

                  } 

                 //Read Data from socket
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
                    int read = 0;
                    Log.d("TCP", "Receive");

                    while ((read = reader.read(mData)) >= 0)
                    {
                        if(read > 0){
                        Log.d("TCP", "DATA!!");                     
                        msg = h.obtainMessage();
                        s="";
                        for(int i=0; i<read;i++){
                            s=s+Character.toString(mData[i]);
                        }

                        bundle.putString("TCP", s);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        h.sendMessage(msg);

                    }
                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                 }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
            }

            }                               
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

}
```